# MPI, I changed a very simple program to use INT instead of CHAR as the data type of the messages buffer and now it fails, why is that?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I took [the MPI example on the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface#Example_program) and modified it to use integers instead of chars.

The result is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int buf[4];
    int my_rank, num_procs;

    /* Initialize the infrastructure necessary for communication */
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    /* Identify this process */
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);

    /* Find out how many total processes are active */
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &num_procs);
    int test[4] = {0, 1, 2};

    /* Until this point, all programs have been doing exactly the same.
       Here, we check the rank to distinguish the roles of the programs */
    if (my_rank == 0) {
        int other_rank;
        printf("We have %i processes.\n", num_procs);

        /* Send messages to all other processes */
        for (other_rank = 1; other_rank < num_procs; other_rank++)
        {
            memcpy(buf, test, 4 * sizeof(int));
            MPI_Send(buf, sizeof(buf), MPI_INT, other_rank,
                     0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }

        /* Receive messages from all other process */
        for (other_rank = 1; other_rank < num_procs; other_rank++)
        {
            MPI_Recv(buf, sizeof(buf), MPI_INT, other_rank,
                     0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
            printf("%d\n", buf[other_rank]);
        }

    } else {

        /* Receive message from process #0 */
        MPI_Recv(buf, sizeof(buf), MPI_INT, 0,
                 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        memcpy(buf, test, 4 * sizeof(int));
        MPI_Send(buf, sizeof(buf), MPI_INT, 0,
                 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    }

    /* Tear down the communication infrastructure */
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Apparently the code should do the same thing as before bug passing an array of integers instead of strings, in practice I receive this error:

```
YOUR APPLICATION TERMINATED WITH THE EXIT STRING: Illegal instruction
(signal 4) This typically refers to a problem with your application.
Please see the FAQ page for debugging suggestions
```

Is there something I am doing wrong here?

I'm compiling and executing with this simple command:

```
mpicc example.c && mpiexec -n 4 ./a.out
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Review `int MPI_Send(const void *buf, int count, MPI_Datatype datatype, int dest, int tag, MPI_Comm comm)` and others.

`count` is number of elements in send buffer, not its *size*.

Code should have been:

```
// MPI_Send(buf, sizeof(buf), MPI_INT, other_rank, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);`
MPI_Send(buf, sizeof buf /sizeof buf[0], MPI_INT, other_rank, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);`
```

Check `MPI_Recv();` and all like calls too. [@Gilles Gouaillardet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48599043/mpi-i-changed-a-very-simple-program-to-use-int-instead-of-char-as-the-data-type/48599903?noredirect=1#comment84205192_48599903)

Comment: same thing for `MPI_Recv()` too

Comment: You are right! The proper answer in my toy case it to use 4 as a parameter.